# redirectTo a path with dynamic and static part

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Check this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/C9W0pHvy27J83m25YUOJ?p=preview

The plunkr works but actually it should NOT work!

These are the routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectListComponent  ,   children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'tests', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: ':id/tests', component: TestsListComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

The `redirectTo` points to `tests` path, but `tests` path does not exist.

In my opinion the `redirectTo` should be `:id/tests`.

Or does the router exclude the **dynamic** `:id` path part and just regards the **static** path part?

I could not find that info at: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I can't reproduce. I couldn't find where your `''` child route is hit at all. Your `Tests` link directly points to `projects/1/tests`. If you have a routerLink with only `/projects` as path, then this redirect is hit, but that doesn't work as expected https://plnkr.co/edit/iP2eI0YTiA96FmJrfJ2v?p=preview

Comment: No need to reproduce anything, I just wanted an answer on my question about the dynamic/static path part ;-) imo everything in the plunkr works as excepted only /projects/1 throws not found url exception, but that should be solved by a 404 route.

Comment: I have seen your tests (default) link, but I do not understand its purpose ;-)

Comment: I don't really understand the problem or question. `redirectTo: 'tests',` shouldn't work. The redirect would need to be `redirectTo: '123/tests',` for it to match the `TestsListComponent`. Can you please try to make it more clear what the current behavior is and what the expected behavior is?

Comment: But I am totally with you! As said that before that redirectTo: 'tests' should not work but it DOES work! And I asked why!? Because redirectTo: ':id/tests' does NOT work! Hallelujah its tuesday :P

Comment: I don't get why you think it's DOES work. When I tried it, it didn't work. `redirectTo: ':id/tests'` is not supposed to work. only `redirectTo: '123/tests'` (with a concrete id value)

Comment: sometimes I wish to easily capture a web video and just put a link here, let me find such a site!

Comment: I was just playing with google chrome screencastify ;-) Of course I tell you:  https://plnkr.co/edit/eWGax56YCYMQrV0Kdm7y?p=preview the redirectTo has now ':id/tests' I could swear that must work it I had it working before. But anyways I think my question about the dynamic/static part is clear, I just can`t find the answer in the documentation as it lacks a proper sample.

Comment: If this works, then I'm sure `:id` is used literally as `id` parameter value, and that's probably not what you want.

Comment: This could be... to make it short hopefully so the redirectTo: 'value' the value refers to 'tests' in my case which is static and not the ':id' dynamic part right? Any source link?

Comment: What `'value'` are you talking about? I don't know about any docs except http://angular.io and I'd be surprised if this were explicitly mentioned.

Comment: The 'value' in my example is 'tests' but it could be replaced with any static value.

Answer (score 0):

`:id/tests` is matched since :id can be any string even empty as well.